# Uploading data to google cloud storage bucket using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am uploading locally stored .mat file with 1.8KB to google cloud from MATLAB using fillowing gsutil command

```
gsutil cp -f data.mat gs://mytestbucket/
```

Uploading data takes more than 2 seconds.

```
Copying file://data.mat [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]... 
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  1.8 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  1.8 KiB/  1.8 KiB]                                                  
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.8 KiB.
```

**Elapsed time is 2.686053 seconds.**

I want to upload data in milliseconds.
How can I upload so that the uploading time is small in milliseconds.

Comment: This totally depends in your internet connection and other factors. Not much you can do for the size of the file. At most using a bucket nearest your location but I don't think you can reach milliseconds. Can you share why you want the file to be uploaded faster?

Comment: @puteri I want to upload the files for real-time purposes. The measurements are taken in every  20ms window. I want to upload the measurements as soon as they are taken, and as soon as data reaches google cloud, I want to do real-time analysis.

Comment: As mentioned above it may depend on internet speed and cloud server location try using a faster internet connection and choose a cloud server that is closer to your location.

Comment: The internet speed is not an issue. I suppose while uploading data to GCP using gsutil. Some socket (or port or some script) opens and closes every time. Like TCP/IP connection, if the socket remains open till the data transfer happens. This may improve the uploading time issue.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/99234-matlab-google-cloud-storage

Comment: @Sugandh thanks for the extra detail. From what you mention using Gsutil is not the best way in general, I think you need to create your own solution for this using the GCS libraries or using another approach. The approach will depend totally on what you need but for sure gsutil is not the option. If you need necessarily GCS, then create your own code in matlab so when the file is created it is uploaded using the libraries or even better stream the data to GCS to avoid creating the file in local which consumes time and don't depend on gsutil

Comment: @Puteri thank you for your response. Can you please suggest some library APIs or approachs to streaming the data in real-time to GCP? This will help me a lot.

Comment: You can stream data in real time using  REST API, [pub/sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) which  is used for streaming analytics,have you gone through the [Client Library for MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332580) which is shared in above comment is that helpful?

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I am using that library. This issue coming in this library. For That reason, I am looking for other options.